# How can i host signalr on a dedicated server

Tags: signalr, blazor, signalr-hub, azure-signalr

I am working on a blazor application.

I have tried azure signalr services (ASRS).

All signalr requests are handled by a dedicated azure resource. So it suppose this reduce load on web server.

What i want to do is to deploy a dedicated signalr server like ASRS but on my own bare-metal server.

I have read some documentation about self-hosted azure but this is not the same thing than ASRS because ASRS does not host Hubs. Hubs stays on web server.

How can i do this ?

Thanks